# Android Layout: Why don't the TextView and a ToggleButton align

Tags: android, alignment, textview, togglebutton

I'm trying to put a TextView and a ToggleButton in a table row, however, they don't seem to align (The top of the button starts about 10px below the top of the textview even though the height each element is the same. Can anyone tell me why?

```
<TableLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >
    <TableRow>
        <AutoCompleteTextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

        <ToggleButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
        </TableRow>

        </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TableRow behaves like LinearLayout and tries to align widgets with text along their baseline by default. Set `android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"` (or any other gravity setting) on your ToggleButton if you'd like it to align differently.